# How can I dynamically allocate memory for a string read from a txt file in C ? More specifically, how can I read this string into a field of struct?

Tags: c, string

I have a struct Art. I want to create a function to read a txt file into a vector of pointers to structs.

```
struct art {
    char *author;
    char *title;
};
typedef struct art Art; 

Art *readFile(Art **vec, FILE* file);

int main(void){
    FILE *file = fopen("filename.txt","r");
    if (file==NULL){
        printf("Failed");
        return NULL;
    }
    Art **vec = (Art**)malloc(150*sizeof(Art*));
    vec = readFile(vec,file);
    return 0;
}

Art *readFile(Art **vec, FILE* file){
    // I want to allocate memory for each of the strings, they have to be of size 80.

    while(fscanf(file, "%[^;];%[^;];", x, y) ==2); //the author and title are separated by semicolons in the file
    

    return vec;
}
```

What should I put in the x and y values???

Comment: If you know they are no longer than 80 chars, use local arrays: `char x[81], y[81];` Then you can duplicate them in the struct with `strdup` or `malloc` + `strcpy`.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp but in the declaration of the struct, they need to be declared as pointers, and then, when reading them, they have to be allocated dynamically. I didnt understand how duplicating them would work... could you be more precise, pls?

Answer (score 0):

If you know they are no longer than 80 chars, use local arrays: `char x[81], y[81];` Then you can duplicate them in the struct with `strdup` or `malloc + strcpy`.

```
struct art {
    char *author;
    char *title;
};
typedef struct art Art; 

int readFile(Art **vec, int array_length, FILE* file);

int main(void) {
    FILE *file = fopen("filename.txt","r");
    if (file==NULL){
        printf("Failed");
        return NULL;
    }
    Art **vec = malloc(150 * sizeof(Art *));
    int num_read = readFile(vec, 150, file);
    return 0;
}

int readFile(Art **vec, int array_length, FILE* file)
{
    int count = 0;
    char author[81], title[81];

    while (fscanf(file, " %80[^;];%80[^;];", author, title) == 2) {
       Art *tmp = malloc(sizeof(*tmp));
       if (!tmp) break;
       tmp->author = strdup(author);
       tmp->title = strdup(title);
       vec[count++] = tmp;
       if (count == array_length) break;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: It might be better to read the whole line with `fgets` then parse that with something like `sscanf`, but OP does not state the data is on separate lines.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I dynamically allocate memory for a string read from a txt file in C ?

Read a *line* is file input into a *string* with `fgets()`.  It is prudent to enforce a (generous) maximum line length.

```
#define AUTHOR_SIZE 80
#define TITLE_SIZE 80
#define LINE_MAX_LENGTH (AUTHOR_SIZE + 1 + TITLE_SIZE + 1)
#define BUFFER_SIZE (2*LINE_MAX_LENGTH) // Detect overly long lines

char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, file)) {
  // Yeah, we have read a file _line_ now saved as a _string_.

  //  TBD code to deal with invalid lines, like ones way too long
  if (strlen(buffer > BUFFER_SIZE - 1)) {
    break;
  }

  // Maybe lop off the trailing \n
  buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = '\0';
  
  // Now parse it
  int n = 0;
  author[80];
  title[80];
  int n = 0;
  sscanf(buffer, " %79[^;]; %79[^;]; %n", author, title, &n);

  // TBD code to handle malformed lines.
  if (n == 0 || buffer[n]) {
    // Scan failed or extra junk at the end
    break;
  }
```

> More specifically, how can I read this string into a field of struct?

Instead of saving a *string* into a `struct`, consider saving a pointer to a *string* in the `struct`

```
  vec->author = strdup(author);  // Or other string duplicating code
  vec->title = strdup(title);
```

---

Be sure to free these duplicated strings when done.